# Restrição Django FileField em Imagem e Video

Tags: django, file-upload

Gostaria de saber como posso limitar o tipo de arquivo no `FileField` do Django?

Sei que posso adicionar essa validação no Form. Gostaria apenas que pudessem enviar videos e imagens nesse campo, nada além disso.

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei uma forma de identificar o mime type do arquivo. Segue o exemplo do form onde eu limito a imagem e video e não permito arquivos .bmp:

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ("file", "name", "email", "subject", "message",)

    def clean( self ): 
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        file = cleaned_data.get( "file", None )
        if file:
            if file.content_type.split('/')[0] not in ['image', 'video']:
                raise forms.ValidationError( 'Enviar apenas video ou imagem.' )
            if file.content_type == 'image/bmp':
                raise forms.ValidationError( 'Arquivos .BMP não permitidos.' )
        return cleaned_data
```